# Convert Anamorphic Pixels to Square Ones and Preserve Displayed Image Size

Tags: video-editor, video-quality, non-square-pixels

Given a video with anamorphic pixel aspect ratio (see the screenshot from `HandBrake`).

[image]

What I need is to stretch the images stored in the video stream (in other words, to convert the video to `1:1` pixel aspect ratio). So, the converted video should have the following parameters:

```
- Storage Size: 758x540
- Display Size: 758x540
- Pixel Aspect: 1:1
```

The only way that currently I can think up is to export the images, scale them by means of a bash utility like `convert`, and assemble them back into a video.

Are there any simpler ways to do that?

**Notes:** I'm currently using `HandBrake`, `MKVToolNix GUI`, and `Kdenlive` on `Ubuntu` OS. Any other software recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution. In `HandBrake`, set `Anamorphic` to `None`, tick `Allow Upscaling`, and change `Scaled Size`. Unticking `Automatic` may also be needed. If so, playing with the first value in `Display Size` and second value in `Scaled Size` may be required.

[image]